# Can't save to Cloudkit public database after saving to custom zone in private database

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Good evening,

I have run into the issue of getting the following error message from Cloudkit when trying to save a record to the public database:

```
"Server Rejected Request" (15/2027); server message = "Custom zones are not allowed in public DB";
```

I have been able to find the issue causing this error. Within this application I need to fetch zone changes on the private database so I have had to save my records to a custom zone in order to accomplish that fetch.

The following code is where I am saving to the custom zone on the private database:

```
    let zoneID = CKManager.defaultManager.sharedZone?.zoneID

    let deckSetToBeSaved = deckName.deckToCKRecord(zoneID)

    privateDatabase.save(deckSetToBeSaved) { (record, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let record = record {
                deckName.cKRecordToDeck(record)

                try? self.managedContext.save()

            }
         }

        print("New record saved")
        print(error as Any)

    }
}
```

Here is my code for saving a record to the public database:

```
func shareDeckPlan(_ deck: Deck, completion: @escaping (Bool, NSError?) -> Void ) {

  var records = [CKRecord]()

  let deckRecord = deck.deckToCKRecord()
  records.append(deckRecord)

  let reference = CKReference(record: deckRecord, action: .deleteSelf)

  for index in deck.cards {
    let cardRecord = index.cardToCKRecord()
    cardRecord["deck"] = reference
    records.append(cardRecord)

  }

  let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: records,  recordIDsToDelete: nil)

  operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = {(savedRecords, deletedIDs, error) in

    if error == nil {

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if let savedRecords = savedRecords {

                for record in savedRecords {
                    if record.recordID.recordName == deck.ckRecordID {
                        deck.cKRecordToDeck(record)

                    }

                    for cards in deck.cards {
                        if record.recordID.recordName == cards.ckRecordID {
                            cards.ckRecordToCard(record)
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            let _ = try? self.managedContext.save()

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                completion(true, error as NSError?)

            })
        })

    } else {

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            print(error!)

            completion(false, error as NSError?)

        })

     }

  }


 operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated

 self.publicDatabase.add(operation)

}
```

The following code referes to the deckToCKRecord method:

```
 func deckToCKRecord(_ zoneID:CKRecordZoneID? = nil) -> CKRecord {

    let deckSetName: CKRecord

    if let ckMetaData = ckMetaData {
        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: ckMetaData as Data)
        unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = true
        deckSetName = CKRecord(coder: unarchiver)!
    }

    else {

        if let zoneID = zoneID {
           deckSetName = CKRecord(recordType: "Deck", zoneID: zoneID)
           self.ckRecordID = deckSetName.recordID.recordName
        } else {
            deckSetName = CKRecord(recordType: "Deck")
            self.ckRecordID = deckSetName.recordID.recordName
        }

    }

    deckSetName["name"] = name! as CKRecordValue
    deckSetName["cardCount"] = cards.count as CKRecordValue

    return deckSetName
}
```

How can I save a record both to the private database in a custom zone and the public database successfully?

Comment: The problem is likely in your `deckToCKRecord()` and/or `cardToCKRecord()` methods. Make sure those methods don't create the `CKRecord` (or its `CKRecordID`) with any reference to a zone.

Comment: Hello @rmaddy, thank you for your reply. I have edited my question with the `deckToCKRecord()` function. `cardToCKRecord()` is the similar in code.

Comment: Is `ckMetaData` set or not? What path is taken through this code when used on your public database? Use the debugger and see where the issue is.

Comment: I will take a look through, thank you.